# can $K, K+l, K+2l,...,K+l^2$ all be primes if $K$ is prime and $l$ $is$ $even$?

Tags: prime-numbers

Given a $K$ prime number and $l$ $is$ $even$ that satisfy $l<K$.

Is it possible that all the $l+1$ numbers : $K, K+l, K+2l, K+3l,...,K+l^2 $ are primes?

I assume no, but I am struggling to prove it.

***Except from the case $K=3$ and $l=2$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume $K$ must be an odd prime?

Comment: yes, otherwise any even $l$ will take $k+l$ to be composite number

Comment: If $l$ is not a multiple of $3$ (hence, of $6$), then one of $K,K+l,K+2l$ is a multiple of $3$, hence, not prime (for $K>3$). So assume $l$ is a multiple of $6$, hence, at least $6$. Then if $l$ is not a multiple of $5$ (hence, of $30$), then one of $K,K+l,\dots,K+4l$ is a multiple of $5$, hence, not prime. So $l$ is a multiple of $30$. But by the same reasoning, now $l$ has to be a multiple of every prime under $30$. And so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nice method :)